# How to enable swagger iu in Quarkus with Reactive Routes?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, vert.x, openapi, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus to build a project and I've decided to use [Reactive Routes](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes).

I'd like to add OpenAPI information and a Swagger UI to my project. It seems like that is possible using [RestEasy](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui) but I didn't find information about the same with Reactive Routes.

Is that possible? I tried to enable it but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really possible.

The RESTeasy approach relies on a combination of reflection and annotations to determine what the REST interface is.
When using Vert.x Web routes you have more flexibility which that that level of information isn't available in a standard way.

There are a couple of alternatives:

- Write the OpenAPI definition up front and use that to generate the routes (https://how-to.vertx.io/web-and-openapi-howto/)
- Find (or write) a generator that constrains your Vert.x code so that it *can* determine the contract dynamically (https://jitpack.io/p/ckaratzas/vertx-openapi-spec-generator is an example, it may not be the only one).

Personally I use RESTeasy if I need to generate OpenApi docs.

Comment: Yep, I saw those both options. But, I also found this: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/10980 I think is coming to the next release (1.7.0) :D